# Import csv from different path with dictionary python

Tags: python

I'm trying to import a CSV from a different path indicating the specified path with a dictionary.

```
import csv
import os
import pandas as pd

PATH = Path("../../Toxic-comment-classification")
PATH.mkdir(exist_ok=True)

args = {
    "data_dir": PATH,
}

class MultiLabelTextProcessor(DataProcessor):

    def __init__(self, data_dir):
        self.data_dir = data_dir
        self.labels = None


    def get_train_examples(self, data_dir, size=-1):
        filename = 'train.csv'
        data_df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(data_dir, filename))
        return(data_df)

a = MultiLabelTextProcessor(args.values())
print(a.get_train_examples(a.data_dir))
```

However, I get the following error when I try to run :

> TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not dict_values

I understand args.values() gives me a dict_object. How can I just have my value from my dictionary as a string ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously you are using Python 3. `args.values()` does not give you a dict object, but a `dict_values`, which the equivalent in Python 2 was a list. However, in your case, the list/dict_values has only one item, i.e. `args.values() == [PATH]` (sort of)

I bet you expect the `args` is a dict with only one entry so you want to extract that `PATH` content. You can simply do `list(args.values())[0]` on it. Or, in my opinion a better way, just use `args['data_dir']`

`os.path.join(data_dir, filename)` with `data_dir` a list or dict_values type and `filename` a string type is causing problem on your code.